# OSB 12c Send Cookie in header

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, osb, oracle-service-bus

thanks in advance for the help!.

Well basically i have a business service and i have to send a request  and also a header, in that header i need to put a Cookie, in oracle page documentation saids

> To set a cookie using a complex XML expression, which is the Oracle Service Bus default format, configure the value of the HTTP Cookie header in the outbound request using the following expression syntax:

`<cookie-values xmlns="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http"> <value>{fn:concat("cookie_name", "=", "cookie_value")}</value> </cookie-values>`

in the routing component i have a transport header like this

[image: enter link description here]

according to the documentation i send in XQuery expression this

[image]

But everytime i send the request the log show

[image]

i try use fn-bea:inlinedXML function to return an xml type or wrap it with quotes but always return the same error

and also i try to test the business service directly with the structure according oracle's page in bus console and i succesfully send with the Cookie

Thanks in advance (sorry for my english if you see any error)
Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue today.  I solved it by adding the following Java options on `setDomainEnv`:

```
-Dcom.bea.osb.http.cookieAsNoComplexElement=true
```